# Calculated column % Complete based on value of other column?

Tags: calculated-column

I am new to SharePoint. I'm trying to figure out how to create tasks that display the percentage complete based on the value of other columns. I'm having trouble with the syntax. I have three columns that will dictate the percentage of completion based on the selected value. How do I write this formula?

Comment: What version of SharePoint?  On prem or online?

Comment: You need to tell us a little more. For example, what's in these columns? Text, Numbers, Yes/No?